# System of linear and nonlinear diff equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for a help with solving this chemical-engineering problem. Is there anybody, who can help?

The task is about this:
Concentration profiles $cA,dA$ during extraction of A-component from solvent C into solvent B in countercurrent colony with axial mixing of continual phase of solvent B are described with following diff equations which I have to solve:
\begin{align}
dA'' &= -(uB/E)\, dA'-kL \,(cA-dA/psi)\\
cA' &= -(kL/uC)\, (cA-dA/psi),
\end{align}

where $cA,dA$ represent concentrations of A-component in original and new solvent, $kL$,$uB$,$uC$,$E$ are constants, "psi" is partition coefficient. Then we have following initial and boundary conditions - z=0 m is inlet of feedstock, z=2 m is inlet of extraction agent.

- $cA(0) = 100$
- $uB* \,dA(2)+E\,* dA'(2) = 0$
- $dA'(0) = 0$

Firstly, I have to solve it for $psi = 100$ (at this moment system of diff equations is linear) and find value for $cA(2)$ in raffinate then. Then I have to calculate using shooting method and then use proper Runge-Kutta approximation (using $psi = 10*sqrt(dA)$, for non-physical option $dA$ $=<0$ I have to use $dA/psi = 0$).

Firstly I want understand the problem in general - the final numbers are not important. I want to try it using your advices (or some similar problems which I can use in my solution) and how to use the substition for the diff equation with rate 2, then how to calculate three diff equations with rate 1 with these written conditions for both cases - linear and nonlinear.

Thank you, J.

Comment: This, [System of differential equations - linear system, shooting method](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3071348/115115), looks similar. Is this a duplicate?

Comment: Yes, its the same, but this version should be more clear for understanding. And I have not understand the comments below the task on that link..

Comment: The comments were about a typographical problem. You should be able to understand the answers. What tools do you have available? You need a numerical ODE solver and a routine to find roots of scalar functions.

Comment: Maple. But for the analytic solution, I should do it on paper, without any software.

Comment: Then I hope your constants are nice numbers. You need to compute the eigen-decomposition of a $3\times 3$ matrix. What does "rate 1" mean? // You can use the full library of Maple? There should be a BVP solver in there.

Comment: rate 1 = order 1 of course, sorry about that (-:

Comment: The order-1 system is also nicely explained in the answer of Christoph in the other post.

Comment: And yes, I hope it does that. I mean the BVP solver.

Comment: In the nonlinear case $\psi(dA) = 10 \sqrt{dA}$ you can eliminate $dA$ using the second ODE: $dA = 100 \left(\frac{uC}{kL}\right)^2 \left( cA’ + \frac{kL}{uC} cA \right)^2$ (please verify). Computing the first two derivatives and inserting into the first equation yields a single third-order nonlinear ODE for $cA$. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

For $\psi = C^{te}$. The linear DE system has the structure

$$
dA''+a* dA'+b* cA-b *dA/\psi = 0\\
cA' +c* cA-c*dA/\psi=0
$$

or

$$
\left(\partial^2+a\partial-\frac{b}{\psi}\right)dA =-b*cA\\
\left(\partial +c\right)cA=c*dA/\psi
$$

or

$$
\left(\partial +c\right)\left(\partial^2+a\partial-\frac{b}{\psi}\right)dA +b*c*dA/\psi = 0
$$

or

$$
\left(\left(\partial +c\right)\left(\partial^2+a\partial-\frac{b}{\psi}\right)+\frac{b*c}{\psi}\right)dA=0
$$

so

$$
dA = C_1 e^{r_1 t}+C_2 e^{r_2 t}+C_3 e^{r_3 t}
$$

where $r_k, k = 1,2,3$ are the differential operator characteristic values (roots)

and then

$$
cA = -\frac 1b\left(\partial^2+a\partial-\frac{b}{\psi}\right)dA
$$

so now we have $dA, cA$ with three constants to determine, ($C_k$) using the boundary conditions. For the linear DE system no shooting method is needed.

NOTE

Applying the differential operator on $dA$ we get at

$$
dA = C_1 e^{r_1 t}+C_2 e^{r_2 t}+C_3 e^{r_3 t}\\
cA = \frac{\left(b-\psi  r_1 \left(a+r_1\right)\right)C_1}{b \psi }e^{r_1 t}+\frac{\left(b-\psi  r_2 \left(a+r_2\right)\right)C_2}{b \psi }e^{r_2 t}+\frac{\left(b-\psi  r_3 \left(a+r_3\right)\right)C_3}{b \psi }e^{r_3 t}
$$

now with the boundary conditions we have

$$
cA(0) = \frac{\left(b-\psi  r_1 \left(a+r_1\right)\right)C_1}{b \psi }+\frac{\left(b-\psi  r_2 \left(a+r_2\right)\right)C_2}{b \psi }+\frac{\left(b-\psi  r_3 \left(a+r_3\right)\right)C_3}{b \psi }=100\\
uB dA(2)+E dA'(2) = uB \left(C_1 e^{2 r_1}+C_2 e^{2 r_2}+C_3 e^{2 r_3}\right)+E \left(C_1 e^{2 r_1} r_1+C_2 e^{2 r_2} r_2+C_3
   e^{2 r_3} r_3\right) = 0\\
dA'(0) = C_1r_1+C_2r_2+C_3r_3 = 0
$$

so we have a linear system to solve for $(C_1,C_2,C_3)$

Comment: I understood the first part of yours, but still I have not deal with founding of the boundary condition that I need...

Comment: @user634771 Please. See note attached.

Comment: In general, I think I get it, but can you tell me what does it mean using this symbol "ϕ". Thanks

Comment: @user634771 Sorry. Is is a typo now corrected.